# Why Quartz's TerracottaJobStore is faster than JDBC

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, terracotta

At [Quartz's official doc](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-09.html) it's said:

> TerracottaJobStore can be ran clustered or non-clustered, and in
>   either case provides a storage medium for your job data that is
>   **persistent between application restarts**, because the data is stored in
>   the Terracotta server. **It’s performance is much better than using a
>   database via JDBCJobStore** (about an order of magnitude better), but
>   fairly slower than RAMJobStore.

*How the benefit in speed (Terracotta over JDBC) is achieved? How and when Terracotta persists quartz' jobs and triggers?*

Comment: It probably has nothing to do with JDBC itself - it simply doesn't use a relational database which eliminates some overhead.

Comment: I would not trust any benchmark which I not falsified myself.   I daresay -. it depends. On a lot of things. You have to decide  for your setup and environment.

Comment: @KonstantinPribluda yeah, it seems like Terracotta setup add some complexity due it requires separate server setup. I wondering if it's worth to spend my time for  that. So I'll decide if to do own benchmarks based on the way they eliminates an overhead of JDBC

Comment: Well, teracotta is big distributed  higly awailable  and sexy - but do you need this? Do you have that many quartz jobs distributed o a millions of boxes?

Comment: @KonstantinPribluda what is an upper limit for Quartz JDBC?

Comment: I have no idea.   But problably very high